# Mutli-Project Gradle - Run bootRun task For Each Child Project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, task

IDE: Spring Tool Suite 4
Framework: Spring Boot
Gradle: v6

I have created a multi-project gradle build consisting of 3 child projects A, B and C. I want to create a custom task in the root build.gradle to achieve the following
Running the custom task will
1) Execute the child project A's bootRun task.
2) Then after few seconds, execute child Project B and C's bootRun task

*bootRun is a task that run the project as spring boot application

Note that child project A is a server, so it will keep running in the background, whereas child project B and C are the client to the project A (server).

Question is how to write such custom task to achieve the above?

Comment: I don't think this is easily achievable because _waiting a few seconds_ is not what gradle tasks do. Can be achieved in a shell with `./gradlew :A:bootRun &; sleep 5s && ./gradlew :B:bootRun :C:bootRun`

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will try that as an option. However,  ignoring the "waiting a few seconds", in the build.gradle, can we achieve parallelism execution for these 3 child projects?

Comment: Indeed you can. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comment to the answer by `smac89`, you have mentioned that "*But I would like to achieve configuring the parallel into the build.gradle file*". In that case, you can create

> gradle.properties

file in the root of the project directory and add the following to it.

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the "*waiting*" part, then this is easily achievable by creating a task that depends on all the other tasks you want to run.

```
task startBootStack(type: GradleBuild) {
    tasks = [
      ':A:bootRun',
      ':B:bootRun',
      ':C:bootRun'
    ]
}
```

Execute with `gradle --parallel startBootStack`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. But I would like to achieve configuring the parallel into the build.gradle file.  In other word, possible to configure parallellism inside the build.gradle, rather than add -parallel as an argument to the command line?